# Parse data from webpage to android app using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

My android app has a part were i need to parse data from wikipedia.com and use that in application. when i go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data I can see the covid19 cases. I want to retrieve the number from the table

[image: screenshot of wikipedia webpage]

I am using Jsoup. I am able to get html data by using this https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data .If you can guide me how can i extract the india cases and deaths from html file. as the html doc is huge and there no attr for tr. There's not much information about this on internet. What i have tried so far...

```
 private void getWebsite() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String web_link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data";
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(web_link).get();
                    String title = doc.title();
                    Elements links = doc.select("tr");


                    builder.append(title).append("\n");
                    for(Element link : links){
                        builder.append(link);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText(builder.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the format of the data (XML). When you navigate down the XML elements, you find what's displayed in the document, when viewed via your browser, is:

```xml
<someTag>...</someTag>
```

But what's actually present is the xml encoded version of the string:

```xml
&lt;someTag&gt;...&lt;/someTag&gt;
```

JSoup won't work well with this and you'll need further processing to convert the output to more XML to get it working I'd imagine. You can test this yourself by viewing the result of:

```java
doc.getElementsByTag("text")
```

And you'd need to replace all `&lt;` and `&gt;` tokens with `<`, `>` respectively.

Here's what I tried, plus some minor edits after failing to be able to pull `tbody`/`thead`/`th`.. I then started trying to pull from the top level tag, starting with `api`, moving deeper into the DOM.

```java
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            String title = doc.getElementsByTag("parse").attr("title");
```

Also worth mentioning there are some really good examples in the documents here: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

And finally, for what it's worth, I'd change the URL used to: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data` to make life easier for use with JSoup so you can just pull the relevant bits of data from HTML rather than XML.

In my view, if you have the choice, HtmlUnit would be a better tool for this since you can simply specify an XPath for the HTML element you want to extract without having to use multiple method calls to get what you want... the more concise format means there's less room for errors to hide.